# Loggin on GUI script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was wondering if someone could assist me in an issue with logging. I created a account tool which uses a gui to unlock accounts, reset password and check  groups etc. I put in the details to Transcript log but it doesn't log any actions other than running the tool then closing it. I wanted to know the best way to go about getting this to either log all and add to a file for each user who runs it or log actions as they are done in a folder for each user or one log for all changes.

Script below is long but for the reference.

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$ADAccountTool                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADAccountTool.ClientSize        = '687,189'
$ADAccountTool.text              = "AD Account Tool For Helpdesk"
$ADAccountTool.TopMost           = $false

$CheckLocked                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckLocked.BackColor           = "#fabc47"
$CheckLocked.text                = "Check Locked"
$CheckLocked.width               = 100
$CheckLocked.height              = 30
$CheckLocked.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,39)
$CheckLocked.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'
$CheckLocked.ForeColor           = "#000000"

$User                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User.multiline                  = $false
$User.width                      = 174
$User.height                     = 25
$User.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,46)
$User.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Header                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Header.text                     = "Enter User"
$Header.AutoSize                 = $true
$Header.width                    = 25
$Header.height                   = 10
$Header.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,26)
$Header.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$UnlockAccount                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$UnlockAccount.BackColor         = "#81b772"
$UnlockAccount.text              = "Unlock Account"
$UnlockAccount.width             = 100
$UnlockAccount.height            = 30
$UnlockAccount.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,39)
$UnlockAccount.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$LockAccount                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$LockAccount.BackColor           = "#e55d5d"
$LockAccount.text                = "Lock Account"
$LockAccount.width               = 100
$LockAccount.height              = 30
$LockAccount.visible             = $false
$LockAccount.enabled             = $false
$LockAccount.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(201,152)
$LockAccount.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$Header2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Header2.text                    = "Set New Password"
$Header2.AutoSize                = $true
$Header2.width                   = 25
$Header2.height                  = 10
$Header2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,87)
$Header2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Password.multiline              = $false
$Password.width                  = 174
$Password.height                 = 20
$Password.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,109)
$Password.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$SetPassword                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$SetPassword.text                = "Set Password"
$SetPassword.width               = 100
$SetPassword.height              = 30
$SetPassword.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,100)
$SetPassword.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$DIsableAccount                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$DIsableAccount.text             = "Disable Account"
$DIsableAccount.width            = 100
$DIsableAccount.height           = 30
$DIsableAccount.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,100)
$DIsableAccount.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$EnableAccount                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$EnableAccount.text              = "Enable Account"
$EnableAccount.width             = 100
$EnableAccount.height            = 30
$EnableAccount.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(420,100)
$EnableAccount.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$GroupMembership                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$GroupMembership.BackColor       = "#f8e71c"
$GroupMembership.text            = "Group Membership"
$GroupMembership.width           = 100
$GroupMembership.height          = 30
$GroupMembership.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(423,37)
$GroupMembership.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$O365Membership                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$O365Membership.BackColor        = "#8cf61f"
$O365Membership.text             = "O365 Membership"
$O365Membership.width            = 100
$O365Membership.height           = 30
$O365Membership.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(537,38)
$O365Membership.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$WS1Membership                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$WS1Membership.BackColor         = "#1c29f8"
$WS1Membership.text              = "WS1 Membership"
$WS1Membership.width             = 100
$WS1Membership.height            = 30
$WS1Membership.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(536,100)
$WS1Membership.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$ADAccountTool.controls.AddRange(@($CheckLocked,$User,$Header,$UnlockAccount,$LockAccount,$Header2,$Password,$SetPassword,$DIsableAccount,$EnableAccount,$GroupMembership,$O365Membership,$WS1Membership))

$CheckLocked.Add_Click({ CheckLocked })
$UnlockAccount.Add_Click({ UnlockAccount })
$SetPassword.Add_Click({ SetPassword })
$DIsableAccount.Add_Click({ DisableAccount })
$EnableAccount.Add_Click({ EnableAccount })
$GroupMembership.Add_Click({ GroupMembership })
$LockAccount.Add_Click({ LockAccount })
$O365Membership.Add_Click({ O365Membership })
$WS1Membership.Add_Click({ WS1Membership })

#Write your logic code here

#Logging is defined here to begin soon as tool is loaded 
#New File is created for logging
New-Item -Path "FOLDERPATH\PowerShell Script Logs\AD Account Tool for SD" -Name "$Env:USERNAME.log"
$LogPath = Join-Path -Path "folderName" -ChildPath "$Env:USERNAME.log"

#Function is created to define the file name and parameters
Function Add-Log ($Message) {
    $Timestamp= $((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))
    Add-Content -Path $LogPath -Value ($Timestamp + ": " + $Message)
}

#Function sets the users password as per input in the password box
function SetPassword { 
    Try {
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User.text -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password.text -Force)
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Password Changed')
}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
    }
}    


#Function checks whether a user is locked in Active Directory
function CheckLocked {
    Try {

$Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
$Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Locked Accounts'

}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
}
}


#Function Unlocks Active Directory account of user.
function UnlockAccount { 
    Try {
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $User.text

    $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Unlocked Account'
}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
}
}


#Function locks a users account and resets password as well
function LockAccount { 
    Try {
if ($LockoutBadCount = ((([xml](Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType Xml)).GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.Account |
            Where-Object name -eq LockoutBadCount).SettingNumber)) {

    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'NotMyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force

    Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, LockedOut |
        ForEach-Object {

            for ($i = 1; $i -le $LockoutBadCount; $i++) { 

                Invoke-Command -ComputerName dc01 {Get-Process
                } -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($($_.UserPrincipalName), $Password)) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue            

            }

            $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
            $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Unlocked Account'
        }
}
}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
}
}



#Function enables a disbaled Active Directory account.
function EnableAccount {
    Try {
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $User.text
    $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Enabled Account'
    }
    Catch {
        Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
        # Add the trapped error to log
        Add-Log -Message $_
    }
}


#Function Disabled an Active Directory account. 
function DisableAccount { 
    Try {
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $User.text
    $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Disabled Account'
}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
}
}


#Function will pull all groups a user is a member off. 
function GroupMembership {
    Try {
    $Result = GET-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.text | Select-Object DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, sAMAccountName, Name
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'User Group Membership'

}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
}
}


#Function Checks if users are part of the required groups for Workspace 1
function WS1Membership {
    Try {
    $Result = GET-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.text |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*GG-View_app*"} | Select-Object DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, sAMAccountName, Name
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Workspace1 Membership'

    }
    Catch {
        Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
        # Add the trapped error to log
        Add-Log -Message $_
    }
}

#Function Checks if users are part of for Office365 Licence's
function O365Membership { 
    Try {
     $Result = GET-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.text |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*sg-lic_*"} | Select-Object DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, sAMAccountName, Name
     $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Office Licence Membership'

}
Catch {
    Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
    # Add the trapped error to log
    Add-Log -Message $_
}
}

#Logging ends here

#Write-Output
[void]$ADAccountTool.ShowDialog()
```

Thanks all for the help in advance.

Comment: If you want a log for all changes made then best to have a single central log on n a file server. Just create a text file and append entries to it as part of each function/action the script takes. You can get the current user from $env:USERNAME

Comment: @Scepticalist Thank you. The log location is going to be on a file server. The issue i have is that the transcript logging does not log any of the actions but the start and end of the script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the above, implemented in your code for the first two functions. Works fine.

```
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$ADAccountTool                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADAccountTool.ClientSize        = '687,189'
$ADAccountTool.text              = "AD Account Tool For Helpdesk"
$ADAccountTool.TopMost           = $false

$CheckLocked                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckLocked.BackColor           = "#fabc47"
$CheckLocked.text                = "Check Locked"
$CheckLocked.width               = 100
$CheckLocked.height              = 30
$CheckLocked.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,39)
$CheckLocked.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'
$CheckLocked.ForeColor           = "#000000"

$User                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User.multiline                  = $false
$User.width                      = 174
$User.height                     = 25
$User.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,46)
$User.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Header                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Header.text                     = "Enter User"
$Header.AutoSize                 = $true
$Header.width                    = 25
$Header.height                   = 10
$Header.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,26)
$Header.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$UnlockAccount                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$UnlockAccount.BackColor         = "#81b772"
$UnlockAccount.text              = "Unlock Account"
$UnlockAccount.width             = 100
$UnlockAccount.height            = 30
$UnlockAccount.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,39)
$UnlockAccount.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$LockAccount                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$LockAccount.BackColor           = "#e55d5d"
$LockAccount.text                = "Lock Account"
$LockAccount.width               = 100
$LockAccount.height              = 30
$LockAccount.visible             = $false
$LockAccount.enabled             = $false
$LockAccount.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(201,152)
$LockAccount.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$Header2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Header2.text                    = "Set New Password"
$Header2.AutoSize                = $true
$Header2.width                   = 25
$Header2.height                  = 10
$Header2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,87)
$Header2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Password                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Password.multiline              = $false
$Password.width                  = 174
$Password.height                 = 20
$Password.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,109)
$Password.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$SetPassword                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$SetPassword.text                = "Set Password"
$SetPassword.width               = 100
$SetPassword.height              = 30
$SetPassword.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,100)
$SetPassword.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$DIsableAccount                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$DIsableAccount.text             = "Disable Account"
$DIsableAccount.width            = 100
$DIsableAccount.height           = 30
$DIsableAccount.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,100)
$DIsableAccount.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$EnableAccount                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$EnableAccount.text              = "Enable Account"
$EnableAccount.width             = 100
$EnableAccount.height            = 30
$EnableAccount.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(420,100)
$EnableAccount.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$GroupMembership                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$GroupMembership.BackColor       = "#f8e71c"
$GroupMembership.text            = "Group Membership"
$GroupMembership.width           = 100
$GroupMembership.height          = 30
$GroupMembership.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(423,37)
$GroupMembership.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$O365Membership                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$O365Membership.BackColor        = "#8cf61f"
$O365Membership.text             = "O365 Membership"
$O365Membership.width            = 100
$O365Membership.height           = 30
$O365Membership.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(537,38)
$O365Membership.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$WS1Membership                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$WS1Membership.BackColor         = "#1c29f8"
$WS1Membership.text              = "WS1 Membership"
$WS1Membership.width             = 100
$WS1Membership.height            = 30
$WS1Membership.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(536,100)
$WS1Membership.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$ADAccountTool.controls.AddRange(@($CheckLocked,$User,$Header,$UnlockAccount,$LockAccount,$Header2,$Password,$SetPassword,$DIsableAccount,$EnableAccount,$GroupMembership,$O365Membership,$WS1Membership))

$CheckLocked.Add_Click({ CheckLocked })
$UnlockAccount.Add_Click({ UnlockAccount })
$SetPassword.Add_Click({ SetPassword })
$DIsableAccount.Add_Click({ DisableAccount })
$EnableAccount.Add_Click({ EnableAccount })
$GroupMembership.Add_Click({ GroupMembership })
$LockAccount.Add_Click({ LockAccount })
$O365Membership.Add_Click({ O365Membership })
$WS1Membership.Add_Click({ WS1Membership })

#Write your logic code here

#Logging is defined here to begin soon as tool is loaded 
#New File is created for logging
New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -Name "$Env:USERNAME.log"
$LogPath = Join-Path -Path "c:\temp" -ChildPath "$Env:USERNAME.log"

#Function is created to define the file name and parameters
Function Add-Log ($Message) {
    $Timestamp= $((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))
    Add-Content -Path $LogPath -Value ($Timestamp + ": " + $Message)
}

#Function sets the users password as per input in the password box
function SetPassword { 
    Try {
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User.text -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password.text -Force) -ErrorAction Stop
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Password Changed')
    }
    Catch {
        Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
        # Add the trapped error to log
        Add-Log -Message $_
        }
}    


#Function checks whether a user is locked in Active Directory
function CheckLocked {
    Try {
        $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled -ErrorAction Stop | select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
        $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Locked Accounts'
    }
    Catch {
        Add-Log -Message ("Error finding locked user " + $user.text)
        # Add the trapped error to log
        Add-Log -Message $_
    }
}


[void]$ADAccountTool.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own log file.

Create a file:

```
New-Item -Path "folderName" -Name "$Env:USERNAME.log"
$LogPath = Join-Path -Path "folderName" -ChildPath "$Env:USERNAME.log"
```

Create a function to add entry to log with timestamp:

```
Function Add-Log ($Message) {
    $Timestamp= $((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))
    Add-Content -Path $LogPath -Value ($Timestamp + ": " + $Message)
}
```

Then as part of every function, append a log entry e.g.

```
function SetPassword {
    Try {
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User.text -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password.text -Force) -ErrorAction Stop
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Password Changed')
        Add-Log -Message ("Changed password for " + $user.text)
    }
    Catch {
        Add-Log -Message ("Error changing password for " + $user.text)
        # Add the trapped error to log
        Add-Log -Message $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. It does not recognise the catch command. Does it require a reference linked to catch in the creation part of the script?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn;t recognise `Catch`? What error do you get?

Comment: i ddi some playing with it last night. It creates the log but now it doesn't append anything to it. So its as you suggested the log scripting. It works fine so the task are running and actioned. I fails to log it. Before i was getting Catch is not a valid/recognisable function.

Comment: My above code works just fine, so it must be your implementation of it. Edit your post with your current code

Comment: For Catch to trap errors, you need to add -ErrorAction Stop to cmdlets in a Try block.
The code you posted works fine for the Set-Password button - you need to amend all the others.

Comment: I think our paths maybe crossed wired here. Thank your firstly that does work perfectly for any errors the script pulls. I was looking for it to log the actions it performs so if an account is unlocked if testaccount1 had its groups searched. Both errors and changes can be in the same log thats fine. Its meerly if we want to check when something was done. Thank you again. I appreciate the help, i find the logging part hard to get my head round.

Comment: Just check the account afterwards using Get-ADUser etc - you'll need to make sure you query the same DC - use the -Server parameter in all your actions.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that later when i get a moment. Thanks again for the help.